Assign a specific date to a variable in Teradata SQL
I want to assign an earlier date to a variable which can be used in a condition in Teradata SQL.
SELECT A.* , B.*
FROM Table A INNER JOIN Table B
ON A.primary_key = B.primary_key
WHERE Field1 = 'ABC'
and history_date > = date - 2;

I want to assign random dates to the variable date. How do I do it in teradata SQL ?

Teradata SQL itself does not support variables. So the answer would depend on your client tool or whether this is dynamic SQL within a stored procedure. Or perhaps you want a parameterized query, where the SQL text has a ? as placeholder and the client would supply the parameter value.

If it is a Toad Data point . Is there any way where I can assign a data value to the variable

I believe Toad Data Point calls this a "Bind Variable". Check the Quest documentation.
